# three min values for each column and more

Tags: r

The data I have contain pair-wise distance between different locations (x,y,z) and (a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j). See below:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10, 15,1)
y <- rnorm(10, 7,0.1)
z <- rnorm(10, 3,0.01)

distdat <- data.frame(x,y,z)

rownames(distdat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")
```

I need to create another data that include: 1) the column name,  row name of the min, and the minimum three values for each column. So in total, the new data will contain
three column and nine rows. Here is the first rows:

```
col_name <- c("x", "x", "x")
row_name <- c("h", "g", "a")
min_val <- c(14.21208, 14.88804, 14.98797)

newdat <- data.frame(col_name, row_name, min_val)
```

Similarly, we need to repeat this for column y and z.

Comment: Note that `c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")` can be produced with `letters[1:10]`.

Comment: @Imo... thank for the note!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10, 15,1)
y <- rnorm(10, 7,0.1)
z <- rnorm(10, 3,0.01)

distdat <- data.frame(x,y,z)

rownames(distdat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

# find indices of smallest values
idx <- sapply(distdat, order)[1:3, ]

# put everything in a data.frame 
data.frame(col_name = rep(colnames(distdat), each = 3),
           row_name = row.names(distdat)[c(idx)],
           min_val = distdat[cbind(c(idx), rep(1:3, each = 3))]
)
```

Also, with the given seed I could not replicate your example, let me know if I missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Its not real pretty, but this could work:

```
set.seed(123)
x <- rnorm(10, 15,1)
y <- rnorm(10, 7,0.1)
z <- rnorm(10, 3,0.01)

distdat <- data.frame(x,y,z)
rownames(distdat) <- c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j")

distdat$row_name <- rownames(distdat)

select(distdat, x, row_name) %>%
  arrange(x) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  mutate(col_name='x') %>%
  rename(min_val = x) -> newdat_x

select(distdat, y, row_name) %>%
  arrange(y) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  mutate(col_name='y') %>%
  rename(min_val = y) -> newdat_y

select(distdat, z, row_name) %>%
  arrange(z) %>% 
  head(3) %>% 
  mutate(col_name='z') %>%
  rename(min_val = z) -> newdat_z

newdat <- bind_rows(newdat_x, newdat_y, newdat_z)
```

certainly, we could (should) create a function to create those newdat_ dfs, and then run the function for each variable x,y,z.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages to do this. They make transformations much more readable.

```
newdat <- distdat %>%
  mutate(row = rownames(.)) %>%
  gather(col, dist, -row) %>%
  group_by(col) %>%
  arrange(col, dist) %>%
  top_n(-3, dist)
```